# How to set custom ViewController as the content of UIAlertController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertviewcontroller

I have custom ViewController and want to show it as alert. When i do it like below, my custom ViewController does not fill the entire content of the UIAlertController and scroll bar is shown. How to do that and also how to disable scrolling.

```
let alert : UIAlertController =  UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.setValue(myCustomViewController, forKey: "contentViewController")
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: You don't. `UIAlertController` does not support any such customization. Don't use `UIAlertController` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. You might consider presenting your custom view controller in such a way it resembles an alert controller. A tip is to play around with `modalPresentationStyle` of your custom view controller. With that you can make a semi-transparent backgrounded view controller that looks like an `UIAlertController`. For example:

```
myCustomViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
myCustomViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
present(myCustomViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Here's an example

```swift
var content_view_height:CGFloat = 200
var ctrl = MyViewController()
var alert = UIAlertController()

alert.setValue(ctrl, forKey: "contentViewController")
ctrl.preferredContentSize.height = content_view_height
alert.preferredContentSize.height = content_view_height

// you have to adjust the Alert size so it's bigger than your custom Content View Controller
var alert_height:CGFloat = 350
let custom_alert_height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: alert.view,
                attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height,
                relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                toItem: nil,
                attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute,
                multiplier: 1,
                //constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.50 // e.g. half of current view
                constant: alert_height // fixed
        )

alert.view.addConstraint(custom_alert_height);
// then present it
```